# how to capture the same size as shown in android camera preview

Tags: android, kotlin, bitmap, preview, android-camerax

The size and proportions of the captured image are different from what you see in the preview screen.

I want to capture the same size as shown in the preview.

The camera preview screen is located between the non-full-screen views.
[The blue area is the camera preview area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFQS7.png)

layout code is below :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/black">

    <androidx.camera.view.PreviewView
        android:id="@+id/preview"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="120dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottom"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/right"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/left"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/top" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/photo_preview"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="120dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottom"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/right"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/left"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/top" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/top"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:src="@drawable/camera"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:tint="@color/white" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/left"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:src="@drawable/camera"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:tint="@color/white" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/right"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:src="@drawable/camera"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:tint="@color/white" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bottom"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:src="@drawable/camera"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:tint="@color/white" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Code to take a picture

```
private fun takePhoto() {
    imageCapture.takePicture(ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this), object :
        ImageCapture.OnImageCapturedCallback() {
        override fun onCaptureSuccess(image: ImageProxy) {
            val buffer = image.planes[0].buffer
            val bytes = ByteArray(buffer.remaining())
            buffer.get(bytes)

            val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.size)
            
            
            // how to resize??
            

            binding.photoPreview.isVisible = true
            binding.photoPreview.post {
                binding.photoPreview.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
            }

            image.close()
        }

        override fun onError(exception: ImageCaptureException) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Photo capture failed: ${exception.message}", exception)
        }
    })
}
```

The captured image is full screen size

However, I was expecting results at the size shown in the preview

Comment: There is no guarantee that the phone supports capturing a photo at the same aspect ratio as the preview. That said, you might consider expanding your [mcve] to show where you are [configuring the aspect ratio of the preview and the picture](https://developer.android.com/training/camerax/configuration#automatic-resolution).

Answer (score 0):

Use the [CameraController#takePicture](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/view/CameraController#takePicture(androidx.camera.core.ImageCapture.OutputFileOptions,java.util.concurrent.Executor,androidx.camera.core.ImageCapture.OnImageSavedCallback)) API. It automatically crops the saved image to match the FOV of the preview. Alternatively, you can use the [UseCaseGroup](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/core/UseCaseGroup) API. `UseCase`s in the same group have their output cropped to match the WYSIWYG effect.

`CameraController` uses `UseCaseGroup` internally.

Comment: Did you do it in practice or just saw it in the documentation?

Comment: I created those APIs. :) `CameraController`/`UseCaseGroup` are designed to create WYSIWYG effect across UseCases.

Comment: @Xi张熹 Using UseCaseGroup API, imageProxy is not cropped but it has a cropRect and we have to manually crop using [cropping algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67348548/1708390). Is my conclusion correct?